# Spring 4.3.3 - ParameterizableViewController POST method not more supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

After upgrading to Spring 4.3.3.RELEASE i get the error:

> Request method 'POST' not supported

My application is a basic template and the home view is rendered via

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="home.view"/>
```

It works fine on Spring 4.2.8.

Any hint to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ran into the same problem. It turns out that, at some point, the ParameterizableViewController was changed to only support GET and HEAD requests.

We resolved this by replacing the  definition with something like this:

```
<bean id="homeController" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController">
    <property name="supportedMethods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE" />
    <property name="viewName" value="home.view" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <map>
            <entry key="/" value-ref="homeController"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Essentially, this allows you to create a ParameterizableViewController with whatever supported HTTP methods you wish. The second bean creates the mapping so that the path "/" resolves to the defined controller.

Comment: This seems a good solution. It works fine and avoids the implementation of controller classes for a simple views.

Comment: Thank you! You saved my day. We have upgraded some time ago and noone noticed this has changed.

Answer (score 0):

ParameterizableViewController default supported methods are GET,HEAD we are check it with the following code snippet.

```
ParameterizableViewController pvc=new ParameterizableViewController();
            String[] str=pvc.getSupportedMethods();
            for(String x:str) {
                System.out.println(x);
            }
```

in order to add POST or any HTTP method, we need to add this XML tag in our bean tag.

```
<bean id="testUrl"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController">
        <property name="supportedMethods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE" />
        <property name="viewName" value="success" />
</bean>
```